# Generate a random string with a specific bit size in java

Tags: java

How do i do that? Can't seems to find a way. Securerandom doesn't seems to allow me to specify bit size anywhere

Comment: what do you mean by "bit size"?

Comment: example 16 bits, 32 bits and so on

Comment: +1 for counteracting the negative vote given

Answer (score 30):

If your bit-count can be divded by 8, in other words, you need a full byte-count, you can use

```
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
byte[] r = new byte[256]; //Means 2048 bit
random.nextBytes(r);
String s = new String(r)
```

If you don't like the strange characters, encode the byte-array as base64:

For example, use the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte[]%29) and do:

```
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
byte[] r = new byte[256]; //Means 2048 bit
random.nextBytes(r);
String s = Base64.encodeBase64String(r);
```

Comment: +1: Thats what I would have answers. Who ever down voted doesn't appear to be able to explain why they didn't like it.

Comment: System.out.println(s) prints a funny string. Is there any way to keep it alpha-numeric?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this. how to encode the byte-array as base64?

Comment: @theomega: converting random bytes to a `String` like this not only produces unreadable garbage, but can also lose entropy! (i.e. you don't really have 2048 bit of random data). For example when your platform default encoding is UTF-8 then about many of the bytes will not be valid `UTF-8` data and be replaced by `�`.

Comment: @William: I again updated the answer to show how to encode in Base64.
@Joachim: I think you are right, does Java really replace the characters in the String? Or only on the printing/output.

Comment: `new String(bytes)` puts the replacement character whenever it finds bytes not valid in the selected (or default) encoding. On output, it may be replaced again with `(byte)'?'`, if your default encoding does not support this character.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the other answer with a minor detail

```
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[32];
random.nextBytes(randomBytes);
String encoded = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(randomBytes)
```

Instead of simply using Base64 encoding, which can leave you with a '+' in the out, make sure it doesn't contain any characters which need to be further URL encoded.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in a random *unique* 128 bit string, I'd recommend [UUID.randomUUID()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29)

Alternatives would include ...

- http://jug.safehaus.org/
- http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "random String" is not clear in Java.

You can generate random bits and bytes, but converting these bytes to a string is normally not simply doable, as there is no build-in conversion which accepts all byte arrays and outputs all strings of a given length.

If you only want random bytes, do what *theomega* proposed, and ommit the last line.

If you want a random string of some set of characters, it depends on the set. Base64 is an example such set, using 64 different ASCII characters to represent 6 bit each (so 4 of these characters represent 24 bit, which would be 3 bytes.)