# AWS Dynamodb scan using ExclusiveStartKey option

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

For my recent project, I am trying to get data from dynamodb. And it seems everything working fine except I add "exclusiveStartKey" option to my parameters.

Below is my code.

```
function scanDataFromDB(datetime) {
let params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    IndexName: "main-index",
    Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
    ExclusiveStartKey: {
        "message_id": { "S": "20161011175258875925351560"}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#f_up": "date_updated"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":s_time": "2016-10-11 00:00:00",
        ":e_time": "2016-10-11 23:59:59"
    },
    FilterExpression: "#f_up between :s_time and :e_time",
    ScanIndexForward: "true"
};
console.log(params);
docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        //callback(err, null);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        //callback(null, err);
    }
})
}
```

This keep returning "The provided starting key is invalid."

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found out the problem. It took me almost a week. If there is a sort key with partition key, "ExclusiveStartKey" Options must indicate both partition key and sort key.

```
function scanDataFromDB(datetime) {
let params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    IndexName: "main-index",
    Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
    ExclusiveStartKey: {
        "message_id": "20161012114321726034249204",
        "date_updated": "2016-10-12 11:44:09"         
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#f_up": "date_updated"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":s_time": "2016-10-11 00:00:00",
        ":e_time": "2016-10-11 23:59:59"
    },
    FilterExpression: "#f_up between :s_time and :e_time",
    ScanIndexForward: "true"
};
console.log(params);
docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        //callback(err, null);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        //callback(null, err);
    }
})
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I also got the same issue, I added both partition key and sort key and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is looking bash version with both primary and sort keys.
In this example chatRoomId is the primary key (pk) and sort key (sk) is the publishing date for a message. This example shows how to start a query from different cursor.

Basically you must to base64 encode the string representation of dynamo-db map (for pk and sk)

```
aws dynamodb query \
  --table-name chat_message \
  --key-condition-expression 'chatRoomId = :pk' \
  --expression-attribute-values '{":pk": {"S": "6c338caf-a073-40f9-9590-a1f675cdd75d"}}' \
  --starting-token $(echo -n '{ "ExclusiveStartKey": { "chatRoomId": { "S": "6c338caf-a073-40f9-9590-a1f675cdd75d"} , "createdAt": { "S": "2023-03-06T12:10:58.372+00:00" } } }' | base64 -w0) \
  --max-items 2
```